# Adding dotted lines to the LOF and LOT

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am trying to add dotted lines in the table of contents using the `tocloft` package.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

I succeeded in getting them on the table of contents page, but I can't seem to figure out how to get them to show up on my list if figures and list of tables.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand\cfttabdotsep{\cftdotsep} \renewcommand\cfttableader{\cftdotfill{\cfttabdotsep}}` for the LoT and `\renewcommand\cftfigdotsep{\cftdotsep} \renewcommand\cftfigleader{\cftdotfill{\cftfigdotsep}}` for the LoF.

Answer (score 4):

Which document class do you use? With either the `book` or the `report` document class (and the `tocloft` package loaded), dot leaders are enabled by default for `section`, `figure`, and `table` items; there should thus be no need to (re)define the macros `\cftsecleader`, `\cftfigleader`, and `\cfttableader` to enable dot leaders for these items in the table of contents, the list of figures, and the list of tables. To enable dot leaders for `chapter` items, it suffices to run

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

Anyway, it appears that you're using a document class that doesn't enable dot leaders by default for any of these four item types. To enable them, you should execute the following four instructions (note that the macro `\cftdotsep` occurs in all four of them):

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```